# If else statement for jQuery AJAX is not running

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

When I insert the snippet and run it on Stack overflow it says '$ is missing'! However the only problem is the the `if` and `else` statement to check if the booking number is all number is not getting executed. The AJAX function runs and the flow goes to the back end and persists data as well. I'm confused is there any thing wrong in this code?

```js
clickme = function() {
  alert("hiiiiiii")
  var selected = $('input:checked');
  var chosen_emails = [];
  selected.each(function() {
    chosen_emails.push($(this).val());
  });

  var re = /[0-9]/;
  var booking_address = document.forms["contact"]["booking_address"].value;

  var booking_number = document.forms["contact"]["booking_number"].value;
  var booking_message = document.forms["contact"]["booking_message"].value;

  var booking_date = document.forms["contact"]["booking_date"].value;
  alert("booking address is" + booking_address + "booking_number is" + booking_number + "booking message is" + booking_message + "booking date is:" + booking_date);

  array = chosen_emails + "" //converting choosen_emails to string type 

  alert("choosen techies are:" + chosen_emails);

  var currentdate = new Date();
  var request_date = currentdate.getDate() + "/" +
    (currentdate.getMonth() + 1) + "/" +
    currentdate.getFullYear() + " @ " +
    currentdate.getHours() + ":" +
    currentdate.getMinutes() + ":" +
    currentdate.getSeconds();

  var user_email = "${user_email}";

  if (booking_number.length < 8) {
    alert("must not be less than 8 numbers");
  } else if (!re.test(booking_number)) {

    alert("Error: must not contain any characters!");
  } else {
    $(function() {
      $.ajax({ // defining the below function as ajax responsive//
        url: 'service_request', // the function that process the  mapped url name and matching type is going to receive the data//
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
          chosen_emails_1: chosen_emails[2],
          chosen_emails_2: chosen_emails[3],
          chosen_emails_3: chosen_emails[4],
          booking_address: booking_address,
          booking_number: booking_number,
          booking_message: booking_message,
          booking_date: booking_date,
          request_date: request_date,
          user_email: user_email
        }, // function to get the value from jsp page and send it to mapped class function//
        success: function(response) { // if the backend process is success then the function will run by getting the response as its parameter//
          alert(response.message);
        },
        error: function(response) {
          alert("there was an error processing your request");
        }
      });
    });
  }
}

//to set limit for number of checkboxes to be selected

$(document).ready(function() { //Its crucial that we are Wrap the code in ready() callback, so that the code (on change event handler) will be executed after DOM is finished loading (response data)
  $("#table").on("click", function() {
    var limit = 3,
      checkboxes = $(this).find("input:checkbox"),
      valid = checkboxes.filter(":checked").length >= limit;
    if (valid) {
      checkboxes.not(":checked").attr("disabled", valid);
      $('.container').show();
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<div class="container" style="display: none;">
  <p> Enter your details to successfully complete the service request </p>
  <form id="contact" action="" method="post">
    <fieldset>
      <input placeholder="Your Address" type="text" tabindex="1" name="booking_address" required>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
      <input type="text" tabindex="2" placeholder="Your number" name="booking_number" id="booking_number" required pattern="('^\\d+$')" title="Must contain only numbers" required/>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
      <label for="datetime"> select your date and time</label>
      <input type="datetime" id='datetime' placeholder="select date and time" name="booking_date" tabindex="3" required>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
      <textarea placeholder="Type your message here(optional) ...." tabindex="4" name="booking_message" required></textarea>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
      <button name="submit" type="submit" onclick="clickme()" id="contact-submit">Submit</button>
    </fieldset>
  </form>
</div>
<div id="check-emails"></div>
```

Comment: Yo must add jQuery on the predefinen libraries selector on the left of the snippet editor

Comment: The `else` part of your code adds a `document.ready` (`$(function() { ... }`) handler, that executes code on page load. It's too late for that, as the page/document is already loaded (since you have to click somewhere to trigger your function).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your regex matches strings that contain at least one number:

```
var re = /[0-9]/;
re.test('39583902'); // true
re.test('mostly letters but also 1 number'); // true
re.test('entirely letters'); // false
```

Invert the logic of your regex and `if` condition:

```
var re = /[^0-9]/;
...
else if (re.test(booking_number)) {
  alert('Numbers only, please');
}
```

You can also drop all the validation code from your click handler and let the browser handle it:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#contact").on("submit", function(evt) {
    console.log("in the form's submit handler");
    evt.preventDefault();
    // Run your AJAX here
  });
});
```

```css
label {
  display: block;
  margin: 0.5em 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p> Enter your details to successfully complete the service request </p>
<form id="contact" action="" method="post">
    <label>
      Your Address
      <input placeholder="123 Anywhere St." type="text" tabindex="1" name="booking_address" required>
    </label>
    <label>
      Your number
      <input type="text" tabindex="2" placeholder="12345678" name="booking_number" id="booking_number" required pattern="^\d+$" minlength="8" title="Must contain only numbers" required>
    </label>
    <label>
      Select your date and time
      <input type="datetime-local" id='datetime' placeholder="2015-10-21T16:29" name="booking_date" tabindex="3" required>
    </label>
    <label>
      Message (optional)
      <textarea placeholder="Placeholders are for example data, not a prompt." tabindex="4" name="booking_message"></textarea>
    </label>
    <button name="submit" type="submit" id="contact-submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

I've added a `minlength` attribute to the booking number `<input>` and fixed its validation regex (HTML just needs the contents of the regex, and its escape character is `&`; there's no need to escape `\d`).

The browser won't submit a form that doesn't validate, so you can put your AJAX in the form's `submit` handler (not the submit button's `click` handler) and it will only run with valid data. Make sure to call `preventDefault()` on the event so submitting the form doesn't reload the page.